# Pass from HC-05 Data Mode to HC-05 AT Command mode by writing some bunch of code

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide, hc-05

My main problem is to reduce the power consumption of the HC-05 Bluetooth module. As it may be known, such a module consumes lower and lower energy when it is in the AT Command Mode (between 1.5 and 3 mA current). Since my project requires sending real time data that change every 15seconds, I want to keep the module in the AT command mode in the 15seconds that the HC-05 don't receive any data. I obviously believe that this kind of idea/solution will dramatically save the energy of the module. In other words, instead of keeping the module in data mode permanently, it will be set in data mode during 15seconds, and in AT command mode during 15seconds, after that it returns to the data mode and still 15seconds etc... I want to know is there any solution for that ? For example writing a bunch of C code (since my Hc-05 is directly connected to an STM32 board) to pass for the AT commande mode every 15seconds
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any sample code, the answer to your only explicit question

> I want to know is there any solution for that ?

is, "Yes."

Comment: Effectively, I didn't share any bunch of code because I don't know how and from where I can start. I am eagerly looking for anyone who has any idea to start with.